# How to use all CPU in a cluster with PBS

Tags: cpu, cluster

I'm very new to MPI, my apologies if this sounds naive. I have access to an HPC cluster and am trying to run a serial script on a 40-core cluster.  Here is my PBS file:

```
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=40,walltime=5:00:00
#PBS -N name
cd my directory
my command
```

The script executes properly, but the load is only for 1 CPU out of the 40 available. How do I use all of the processors (0-39)?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should try `GNU Parallel`.
The homepage is at [gnu.org/software/parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) and there is some video presentation here [GNU Parallel videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ&list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1).

*(Excuse my wage answer but I don't know what MPI, HPC and PBS is)*